# Power series question.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

How would I go about solving $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n-1)x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$$ So far I have tried to of course consider the exponential power series, but I seem to get negative factorials.

Comment: You won’t get negative factorials if you remove the first term, though. Note $1-1=0$ at $n=1$. Alternatively you can use the convention $(-n)!=\infty$ so $1/(-n)!=0$ for $n\ge1$ an integer. This is correct in some sense.

Comment: This is also $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} n \frac{x^n}{n!}$

Comment: It would have been nice if you had included your best attempt.

Answer (score 14):

Note that

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n-1)x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} &=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-2)!} \\
&=x\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{x^{n-2}}{(n-2)!} \\
&=x\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!} \\
&=xe^x.
\end{align*}